# Excel VBA Sort Based on A String

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to sort a sheet based on a string for example:

```
Column 1 Column 2
name1     x
name2     x
name3     asdad
name4     gadfa
name5     gsdff
```

Is it possible to sort this in a way that it places all rows with a certain string on top, in this case, all rows with the "x" string should be on top first and then it sorts the rest alphabetically based on column 2.

Comment: [Sort records in custom order](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sort-records-in-custom-order-af750db5-67df-4dee-8da8-cc3facc9a75e)

Comment: You can also actually record a macro with this one and edit or remove unnecessary lines :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
Sub Test()
Dim n           As Long

Application.AddCustomList Array("x")
n = Application.CustomListCount

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Sort Key1:=.Range("B1"), Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=n + 1
    .Sort.SortFields.Clear
End With

Application.DeleteCustomList n
End Sub
```

Comment: When I save the excel file after calling the AddCustomList, it crashes though. What would be the cause of this?

Comment: I have added a line to clear the sort in the activesheet. See if this works for you